# FFMpeg fails with LZW decode failed / invalid block label when converting gif to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, video, conversion, video-conversion

I'm using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert gif into mp4 files. On some gif files I encounter an `invalid block label` error. The program seems to still output an okay mp4 file but I'd rather it not encounter the error in the first place. I found the command I used in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40638/how-to-do-i-convert-an-animated-gif-to-an-mp4-or-mv4-on-the-command-line)

```
user@mediaserver:/temp$ ffmpeg -i /temp/input.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" /temp/output.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, gif, from '/temp/input.gif':
  Metadata:
    comment         : Created with ezgif.com video to GIF converter
  Duration: 00:00:01.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 207257 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 600x1067 [SAR 64:64 DAR 600:1067], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] using SAR=1066/1067
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Slow
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/temp/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    comment         : Created with ezgif.com video to GIF converter
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 600x1066 [SAR 1066:1067 DAR 600:1067], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
[gif @ 0x559776c38f00] LZW decode failedB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
[gif @ 0x559776c35b00] invalid block label
[mp4 @ 0x559776c47580] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=   32 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     370kB time=00:00:01.16 bitrate=2614.8kbits/s speed=1.38x
video:369kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.351198%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] frame I:1     Avg QP:24.32  size: 38869
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] frame P:8     Avg QP:24.95  size: 17974
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] frame B:23    Avg QP:26.28  size:  8456
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] consecutive B-frames:  3.1%  0.0%  9.4% 87.5%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] mb I  I16..4: 22.7% 63.6% 13.7%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] mb P  I16..4:  4.6% 21.3%  1.6%  P16..4: 36.5% 12.6%  8.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:15.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] mb B  I16..4:  0.5%  3.6%  0.1%  B16..8: 43.6%  6.9%  2.0%  direct: 3.6%  skip:39.7%  L0:46.6% L1:50.7% BI: 2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] 8x8 transform intra:76.0% inter:81.8%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 60.4% 39.6% 6.8% inter: 18.2% 10.9% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] i16 v,h,dc,p:  4% 16%  5% 75%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 11% 17% 31%  6%  8%  7%  9%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 21% 21%  5%  8%  7%  9%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] i8c dc,h,v,p: 61% 23% 12%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] Weighted P-Frames: Y:12.5% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] ref P L0: 54.5% 10.5% 21.0% 12.8%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] ref B L0: 85.2% 11.4%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] ref B L1: 94.8%  5.2%
[libx264 @ 0x559776c48980] kb/s:2357.26
```

It also fails converting it to gif, which makes sense given the LZW decode failed error in the log. If someone could give me some insight on how to fix this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do the failed GIF files differ? Are they perhaps black & white?

Comment: Gif to gif conversation made the newer gif much smaller and slightly lower quality. Otherwise it worked. Gif to mp4 is same thing, maybe slightly lower quality.